# Why am I getting this error when creating two buttons in python appJar?

Tags: python, sqlite, appjar

I am building a simple GUI using appJar for a library system I made for school. I'm trying to make a function that allows users to either upvote or downvote a book (books are stored in a sqlite3 database) given the book ID (one of the columns for each entry in the db). Here is my code:

```
def upvote(id):
    statement = f"SELECT review from books WHERE id={id}"
    cur.execute(statement)
    rating = cur.fetchall()

    newRating = rating[0][0] + 1
    statement2 = f"UPDATE books SET review={newRating} WHERE id={id}"
    cur.execute(statement2)
    con.commit()

def downvote(id):
    statement = f"SELECT review from books WHERE id={id}"
    cur.execute(statement)
    rating = cur.fetchall()

    newRating = rating[0][0] - 1
    statement2 = f"UPDATE books SET rating={newRating} WHERE id={id}"
    cur.execute(statement2)
    con.commit()

def giveRating():
    app.startSubWindow("Give Rating", modal=True)
    app.show()
    app.setFont(18)
    app.setBg("orange")
    app.setSize(400, 400)

    app.addLabelEntry("Book ID")
    bookId = app.getEntry("Book ID")
    app.addButton("Upvote", upvote(bookId))
    app.addButton("Downvote", downvote(bookId))
    app.stopSubWindow()
```

The reason for using subwindows is that the rating page is opened upon clicking a button from a dashboard page.

Anyone know why I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/guilhermelopes/Documents/terminal library sys/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/appJar/appjar.py", line 3781, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: funcName()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/guilhermelopes/Documents/terminal library sys/app.py", line 83, in giveRating
    app.addButton("Upvote", upvote(bookId))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/guilhermelopes/Documents/terminal library sys/app.py", line 56, in upvote
    cur.execute(statement)
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious but I can't find anything relevant to my issue in the docs. Whilst the input label is created, I expected the two buttons to be created along with it, but instead I get the above error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT review from books WHERE id={id}` What is the type of the `id` column, and what type is the `id` python variable?

Comment: Both are integers.

Comment: My only guess is that you're encountering a case where `id` actually is not an integer.  As a debugging step, can you print `statement` before executing it, to see what it is actually trying to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be the problem, or at least part of the problem:

```
app.addButton("Upvote", upvote(bookId))
```

The way you're referring to `upvote` (i.e. you put parentheses `()` after it), it is called *right now*, instead of *later* when the button is pressed.

In typical GUI apps like this, you would only pass the function *name*:

```
app.addButton("Upvote", upvote)
```

Which would give the button a *reference* to the upvote function that it can call *later* when the button is actually pressed.  (Although in this specific case I don't know how you would do that and also be able to pass the `bookId` argument...)

And indeed, the appjar documentation for `addButton()` does it exactly that way.  http://appjar.info/pythonWidgets/

You're using `addButton()` wrongly.

Comment: Yes, the problem was passing the argument. The way I fixed it was by assigning the bookId value inside the upvote and downvote functions independently. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you selecting the column `review`?
It is not the column that you want to update.
You should select the column `rating`.

But, why do you select anything?

You can do what you want with the `UPDATE` statement only:

```
def upvote(id):
    statement = "UPDATE books SET rating = COALESCE(rating, 0) + 1 WHERE id = ?"
    cur.execute(statement, (id,))
    con.commit()

def downvote(id):
    statement = "UPDATE books SET rating = COALESCE(rating, 0) - 1 WHERE id = ?"
    cur.execute(statement, (id,))
    con.commit()
```

I use `COALESCE(rating, 0)` just in case `rating` is nullable.
If it is not, change to just `rating`.

Also, from http://appjar.info/pythonWidgets/, you should pass only the function's name as a parameter to `addButton`:

```
app.addButton("Upvote", upvote)
app.addButton("Downvote", downvote)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This eliminates the error, but does not update the db. The statement generated is as follows:

UPDATE books SET rating = COALESCE(rating, 0) - 1 WHERE id = ?

The function runs before the button is clicked, and then once the button is actually clicked it doesn't run the function. Do you know what is going on?